# How to remove .php extensions along with loading index.php on directory root

Tags: php, .htaccess

Using the following .htaccess works very nicely for removing the .php extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But unfortunately this does not work well with

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

When combining them togther the `.php` extension remove overrides any `index.php` rules and that results in:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin/statusdir2/.php was not found on this server.
```

I know I could use `http://example.com/index` but that defeats the whole point of the question.

So how could I combined this so both `http://example.com` loads the `index.php` and any other page after this `http://example.com/page` loads `page.php` without them conflicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way in root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Not Found -The requested URL /admin/statusdir2/.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Still coming up with the same issue. I am trying to make it so when they view the directory for example http://example.com/dir/ it will load the index.php which does not conflict with the /dir/.php as it is now.